# Photons produced when high energy positrons hit a target

Tags: particle-physics, particle-accelerators

I recently learned that high energy positrons thermalize (slow down) as they enter matter undergoing bremstrahlung, producing photons. Eventually they will collide with an atom bound electron, with which it will anhialate and produce two pohotons (sometime three but I am not interested in such cases). As I learned today, positrons can anhialite in flight but the photons produced have energies > 511KeV. Therefore my question is: when I have positrons with energies of few GeVs (1-5) bombarding a target, most likely a metal, and photons are produced by bremstrahlung and anhiliation, how can I classify the photons into the two groups (the ones produced by bremstrahlung and the ones produced by anhiliation)? My initial thought was to look for photons with energies of exactly 511KeV, but I am little concerned that some of the photons from bremstrahlung will have this energy too, thus making my hypothesis false. Could you help me with this idea?